# Как сделать приостановку выполнения дочернего потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

В классе **ChildrenThread** нужно реализовать методы для приостановки и продолжения выполнения потока. 
Приведенный мной пример, очень утрирован относительно реальной задачи. 
В методе `run()` выполняется очень долго и у пользователя может возникнуть необходимость приостановить его работу, независимо от этапа выполнения задачи...

```
class ChildrenThread extends Thread {

    private boolean play = true;

    public ChildrenThread() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println(i++);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void play() {
        play = true;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void pause() {
        play = false;
        while (!play) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Пример использования:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ChildrenThread th = new ChildrenThread();

    th.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);

    th.pause();
        Thread.sleep(5000); 

    th.play();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    th.pause();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    th.interrupt();
}
```

В этом примере, выполнение главного потока останавливается при первом вызове `pause()` дочернего потока, а сам дочерний поток продолжает выполнение.

Как сделать так, чтобы при вызове `pause()` приостанавливал свою работу дочерний поток и  продолжал ее после вызова метода `play()`?

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Как сделать приостановку выполнения дочернего потока?

Comment: Вам нужно соответствующим образом поменять вопрос. "Как сделать приостановку выполнения дочернего потока?" - гораздо короче чем то, что вы написали.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал, например, так:

1. Объявил бы приватный [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) ёмкости 1.
2. В методе `run` перед каждой итерацией брал бы его, и тут же отпускал.
3. В методе `pause` забрал бы семафор, а в методе `play` отпустил бы.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, для решения этой задачи, можно сделать так:

```
class ChildrenThread extends Thread {

    public volatile boolean play = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            checkPause();
            System.out.println(i++);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void play() {
        play = true;
        notify();
    }

    public void pause() {
        play = false;
    }

    private synchronized void checkPause() {
        while (!play) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                interrupt();
                play = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хоть это и не совсем то, что я хотел, но пока так.

Мне не понятно, почему нельзя приостановить выполнение потока используя подход из первого поста. Судя по всему, это какое-то ограничение в java, на случай если wait() будет вызван в процессе выполнения какой-то "важной" операции, не завершение которой может привести к потере данных ?...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте немножко видоизменить код самой реализации потока

```
public class ChildrenThread extends Thread {

private boolean play = true;

public ChildrenThread() {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (play) {
        System.out.println(i++);
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!play) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void play() {
    play = true;
    notify();
}

public synchronized void pause() {
    play = false;
}
}
```

А вообще посмотрите в сторону ExecutorService(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Спасибо!   .................................. .